# How to convert substring of varchar to digits before decimal sign and convert substring of varchar to digits after decimal point?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a `varchar(10)`.

How to convert it to a `numeric(10,4)` (where the last 4 characters of the varchar are the 4 digits after the decimal point and the first 6 characters of the varchar are the 6 digits before the decimal point)?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [STUFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function to insert a decimal separator and cast the result string to decimal:

```
declare @s varchar(10) = '1234561234'
select cast(stuff(@s, 7, 0, '.') as decimal(10,4))
```